# Adding items to a sorted list of numbers inside a file without splitting it

Tags: c++, c, file, sorting

I'm searching for the best way to accomplish what's specified in the title. Let's say I have a file ( let's make it a text file for the sake of simplicity ) with a list of pre sorted numbers, such as

```
    0 2 3 4 4 6 12 13 14 16 16 16 17 18 ...
```

I want to insert a new number in this list, let's say **5**, without loading everything into memory and perform the sorting on every item in the file again ( this is just an example, in my case I have a huge amount of data and loading everything into memory is not doable ) and without splitting the file into the "lower bound" and "upper bound" parts ( temporary files ) to rejoin them with the number in the middle.
Is there any way to just insert something in a given position of a file and making everything from that offset on just "shift" for the appropriate number of bytes ?

Solutions with both standard functions such as (f)open, (f)write, etc and Windows specific APIs ( memory mapped files too ) are welcomed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to shift things manually as if it where an array into memory. You probably can speed up thing by mapping portion of the file into the memory.

Comment: yeah I'm 99% sure about it too, but you know, never say never :) I still hope for that 1% to prove me wrong

Comment: OT: I'm wondering why people downvote this question.../OT According to @Andrew McDonnell I don't think that is possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: OT: Yeah I was wondering that too ... sometimes I really can't understand how people judge questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Realistically

Based on how filesystems and operating systems are implemented, I'd say that a solution to the question as posed is impossible.

May I suggest you need a SQL database...

#### Aside

If you were talking about sorted binary records where the size of a record exactly matched the size of a sector on disk, it might theoretically be possible to avoid rewriting data on disk other than file meta-data if you had a hypothetical filesystem that let you insert 'sectors' into the middle of a file.

In theory, anyway, as if such a [strange file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_DOS#1541_Directory_and_file_types) existed  (scroll down to 'REL' file type -- never thought I'd be thinking about this again!) ...

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution you didnt want, what you want is impossible without using  SQL..  but here goes the  temporary files way....

It loads  everything into memory and performs some processing and then writes all items back  into the file again.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




void displaystudentdata()
{
   string name, grade, tname;
    int age, x=0; // x - "counter" to check if user entered wrong name

    system("cls");

    ifstream students("students.txt");


    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    while(students >> name >> grade >> age)
    {

        cout<<"Name= "<<name <<", Grade= "<< grade <<" , Age= " <<age<<"\n";
    }
    students.clear(); // clear eof and fail bits
    students.seekg(0, ios::beg);
     students.close();
}

void deletestudentdata()
{
    string name, grade, tname;
    int age, x=0; // x - "counter" to check if user entered wrong name



    ifstream students("students.txt");
    ofstream temp("temp.txt"); // temp file for input of every student except the one user wants to delete


    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    cout << "Enter name of the student you want to erase from database >" << endl;
    cin >> tname;

    //ifstream students("students.txt");
    //ofstream temp("temp.txt"); // temp file for input of every student except the one user wants to delete

    while(students >> name >> grade >> age)
    {
        if(tname!=name){ // if there are students with different name, input their data into temp file
            temp << name << ' ' << grade << ' ' << age << endl;
        }
        if(tname==name){ // if user entered correct name, x=1 for later output message that the user data has been deleted
            x=1;
        }
    }
    students.clear(); // clear eof and fail bits
    students.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    students.close();
    temp.close();
    remove("students.txt"); 
    rename("temp.txt","students.txt");
    if(x==0){ // x was set to 0 at start, so if it didn't change, it means user entered the wrong name
        cout << "There is no student with name you entered." << endl;
    }
    else{ // x is not 0, it means user entered the correct name, print message that students data has been deleted
        cout << "Student data has been deleted." << endl;
    }
}


int main(void)
{



  displaystudentdata();
  deletestudentdata();
  displaystudentdata();
  cout << "Student data has been deleted. \n\n" << endl;
  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```